# Why do canvas rects drawn with odd widths not overlap properly?

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinates

I am attempting to line up multiple rectangles next to each other in a line using a series of integer x-coordinates, and the width of each rectangle is variable based on the distance between each x-coordinate. The point is to generate a smooth line of different rectangles with different colors.

The sample below demonstrates the method I am using:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
  ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
  height = 70,
  width = 500;
  
// Scale DPI for high-res screens

let dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.width = width * dpi;  
canvas.height = height * dpi;
canvas.style.width = width + "px";
canvas.style.height = height + "px";
ctx.scale(dpi, dpi);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

// Generate random array of x-values with varying distances of 3, 5, & 7

let points = new Array(100 + 1).fill(0).map((n, i) => {
  return i * 5 + (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 2 : 0);
});

// Generate rectangle templates using distance between points

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < (points.length - 1); i++) {
    let point = points[i], nextPoint = points[i+1];
    let width = nextPoint - point;
    result.push([point, 10, width, 50]);
}

// Display sequentially with progressive color (to show effect)

let n = 0;

for (let point of result) {
    let v = Math.floor((n++ / result.length) * 255);
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(50, 50, ${v}`;
    ctx.fillRect(...point);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" />
```

However, as seen in the sample, gaps are visible between some of the rectangles. The behavior seems to have something to do with whether even or odd numbers are used, but I cannot find any data on why this would be an issue. Switching the x-coordinates to all even numbers seems to create a smooth line of rectangles, but this is impractical for my application.

Can this odd behavior be explained?

Comment: What does `dpi` output on your device? You'd want to have the scaling factor be an integer.

Comment: @Kaiido The DPI on my device is 2.5. Given that, what can I do?

Comment: I'd say, ceil it to `3`.